# Why that causes an extra empty line for my out put if the input didnt end up with an digit in JAVA

Tags: java, input, println

Hi I'm a student who studing this and my teacher ask us to wrote a progame that could get the correct output. The request is the input will always start with an integer k, and after the first input there will be k lines of String followed. that means if the k is 4 and after the input k, there is other 4 line of input and all of these inputs are strings. And the request ask that I need to ignore the first k, only look for the second k and print the k lines input after the second k as the output.

What I had tried is I wrote these code blow

```
public class CS220_A1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int firstInt = input.nextInt();
        String temp = new String();
        for (int i = 0; i < firstInt + 1; i++) {
            temp = input.nextLine();
        }
        int secondInt = input.nextInt();
        for(int j = 0; j < secondInt + 1; j++) {
            System.out.println(input.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

The input given as a sample is

```
4
bGTRYLEsJhStPVDMdmoxZle
ZYEDXeMaGotpjAtpcaJQnHyTDXNnhgYMOpIdMBvn
oTRJptFnaMRZNuapwqWYbXIEOothm
aLKzsZAIuyW
3
oi
oii
oiii
0
```

and the output should be

```
oi
oii
oiii
```

My code works well with this sample, however when I do the test by myself, I found out that if the input didn't end up with a Integer (or maybe a digit) the output will be different.
if I let the input as

```
0
3
asc
azxv
aabbb
```

The output will only have "asc"and"azxv" comes out, until I press the enter button.
But it didnt turns to the right side, after I press the enter button, there will be a empty line shows on the result there which cause my output incorrect.

Not sure if the picture works or not. I decide to put the output down here
The incorrect output will shows as below

```
asc
azxv
```

and after I press the enter button, it show as

```
asc
azxv

aabbb
```

There is a empty line come out there! And I try a lot to fix it but I failed.
I want to know how can I fix this problem and I want to know if my idea start with the correct side!
Thanks a lot!

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ74F.png)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < firstInt + 1; i++)` is not correct, and neither is the other loop. First one should be `for (int i = 0; i < firstInt; i++)`, and similarly for the second one.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I tried this but after I changed it it will only output the "asc" and "azxv", after output these two string the program is end, however I want "asc azxv aabbb" all be the output...

Comment: You need to call `nextLine()` after each `nextInt()` call, to consume the end of its line.